# Using STL container to initialize a graph in Lemon Graph Library

Tags: c++, lemon-graph-library

Here is an example of graph initialization from Lemon Tutorial:

```
ListDigraph g;
ListDigraph::Node x = g.addNode();
ListDigraph::Node y = g.addNode();
ListDigraph::Node z = g.addNode();
g.addArc(x,y);
g.addArc(y,z);
g.addArc(z,x);
```

Can the same be accomplished by using a container with arc data? For example:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> arcs = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}};
LemonGraph             g(3, arcs);
```

**EDIT**

I just found that it can be done for `StaticDigraph`, see below:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> arcs = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}};
StaticDigraph          g;

g.build(3, arcs.begin(), arcs.end());
```

Can `StaticDigraph` be easily transformed to modifiable type of graph?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only one constructor, that is default. [docs](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest/a00235.html#abff6c0f71f9067a36468f2919edcac51)